# Перегрузка

Tags: операторы, преобразование, перегрузка-операторов, c++

Доброго времени суток.
Возник такой вопрос: допустим, есть класс с двумя операторами:

```
   #include <iostream>
    using std::cout;

    class CL
    {
    public:
        operator int()
        {
            cout<<"int";
            return 0;
        }
        operator int*()
        {
            cout<<"int*";
            return 0;
        }
    };

    void main()
    {
        CL cl;
        if (cl){}
    }
```

Здесь объект `cl` должен преобразоваться в `bool`, и есть два пути сделать это:

1. преобразовать `CL` в `int`, затем стандартное преобразование `int->bool`
2. преобразовать `CL` в указатель на `int`, затем стандартное преобразование указатель на `int->bool`.
   Вроде бы должна быть неоднозначность, но `VS2008` и `Devcpp` выбирают первый случай. Т.е. получается, что приведение `int` к `bool` имеет больший приоритет, чем приведение указателя к `bool`. В стандарте ничего не нашел (хотя, скорее всего, плохо искал).
   Вопрос: соответствует ли такой приоритет стандарту и можно ли его смело использовать, не опасаясь, что на одних компиляторах это будет работать, а на других - нет?

Comment: А почему не можете пребозраовать сразу в boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таки плохо искали. [Стандарт C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), пункт 13.3.3.2.4.

> — A conversion that does not convert a
> pointer, a pointer to member, or
> std::nullptr_t to bool is better than
> one that does.

Перевод:

> Преобразование, которое не преобразует
> указатель, указатель на член класса
> [метод] или std::nullptr_t к bool
> лучше, чем то, которое преобразует.

То есть, в вашем случае была возможность не преобразовывать указатель к `bool`, и компилятор е воспользовался.